# need help to update database data in a react .map list by properly appending url request

Tags: json, reactjs, database, routes, axios

Short story:
If I can get help figuring out how to append a primary key on a URL/: id properly, I can make a .PUT crud call for restful functionality using react and axios.

Longer story:
I'm working on building a beginner's application.

It has a react front-end using an Axios package for HTTP requests. & Then it has a node.js express back-end using Sequalize to connect to the Mysql database.
[setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwOf8.png)

Currently trying to make an Axios.PUT request in React, to be able to update a React .map list of products. But I have not figured out how to append the /: id to the URL to successfully make updates. or get it to work for crud function.

The back-end receiving endpoint is works coded like such:

```
        router.put("/:id", function (req, res, next) {
          let productId = parseInt(req.params.id);
          models.products
            .update(req.body, { where: { products_id: productId } })
            .then((result) => res.redirect("/products/" + productId))
            .catch((err) => {
              res.status(400);
              res.send("There was a problem updating the products.  Please check the product information.");
              console.log('There was a problem updating the product.  Please check the product information.');
           });
        });
```

Making GET & POST front end calls went well too, show below:

```
        .
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { productData: [] };
    this.productName = React.createRef();
    this.productPrice = React.createRef();
  }

  fetchProductData = () => {
    let url= http://localhost:3001/products;
    return axios.get(url).then(response => this.setState({ productData: response.data }));
      };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchProductData();
  }

  addProduct = () => {
    let url = http://localhost:3001/products;
    return axios.post(url, { name: this.productName.current.value, price: this.productPrice.current.value }).then(response => {
      // refresh the data
      this.fetchProductData();
      // empty the input
      this.productName.current.value = "";
      this.productPrice.current.value = "";

    });
  };
```

My problem & question comes with making a PUT & Delete front-end react Axios-calls for a .map list that shows a list of products in my database. the render() shows up fine and works for the Post and Get routing.

I could use help sorting out a way to properly append the: id to the URL of the Axios call for the updateProduct() and the deleteProduct() such that with inputs, I can push a button, and then the .map list updates or deletes single items from the list and my database.
I'm lost as to how to get the buttons to work with the correct product key on click as well.

```
         
  updateProduct = () => {
    let url = `http://localhost:3001/products/${product.products_id}`;
    return axios.post(url, { name: this.productName.current.value, price: this.productPrice.current.value }).then(response => {
      // refresh the data
      this.fetchProductData();
      // empty the input
      this.productName.current.value = "";
      this.productPrice.current.value = "";

    });
  };

  deleteProduct = () => {
    let url = 'http://localhost:3001/products' + ${product.products_id};
    return axios.delete((url)).then(response => {
      // refresh the data
      this.fetchProductData();
      // empty the input
      this.productName.current.value = "";
      this.productPrice.current.value = "";

    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.productData);
    if (this.state.productData.length === 0) {
      return <div>Failed to fetch data from server</div>;
    }
    const products = this.state.productData.map(product => (
      <div key={product.products_id}>
        <em>{product.name}</em>: ${product.price} <button ref={this.updateId} type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.props.updateProduct()}>Update</button><button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.props.deleteProduct()}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>List of products (React, added this code)</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="New Product" ref={this.productName} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Given Price" ref={this.productPrice} />
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addProduct}>add</button>
        {products}
      </div>);
  }
}

export default Products;
```

[render() of list result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeYJh.png)
I've been on this for about a week, and I have done a good amount of searching, yet have not figured it out yet. apologies I'm a beginner. so maybe you guys can assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already iterate on your products list, so you have access to product id.

```
deleteProduct = (id) => {
    let url = `http://localhost:3001/products/${id}`;
    return axios.delete((url)).then(response => {
      // refresh the data
    });
  };

this.state.productData.map(product => (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(product.id)}>Delete</button>
)
```

Comment: I believe the id parameter should fix the delete and put function. I appreciate it.

however, I'm still getting a "can't read null" error when I try placing my products tables primary key of "products_id inside the Button tags onClick function call.

Comment: <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(product.products_id)}>Delete</button>